# Fixing the 1px gap of 3 container with width of 33.333%

Tags: css, material-ui

This is hard to explain in words but I see a 1 pixel line of 3x containers of width of 33.3333% and I can't change that as its part of `material-ui`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel" style="width:width of 33.3333%">
        <!-- Content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="width:width of 33.3333%">
        <!-- Content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="width:width of 33.3333%">
        <!-- Content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

So here what I'm getting, and i only because its 33.333%, set it to 25% or 50% and the problem goes away, i have marked the pixel line with a bit of red (paint).

[image]

This is the `material-ui` `<gridList>,` `<GridItem>` and `<Cards>` and its quite fustrating.

*EDIT*

Trying out `33.33 / 33.33 / 33.34` still returning 1px gap!

Comment: Most probably this is going on on Chrome and not in Firefox, correct?

Comment: @BramVanroyI have not tried this in firefox, chrome as its <50% market share, all other browser don't matter right now.

Comment: This question [has been asked frequently](https://www.google.be/search?q=chrome+1px+gap+percentage) but it's a bug and as noted below, a rounding issue. No 'good' solution is available I'm afraid.

Comment: @BramVanroy alright, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

33.333 is not the same as 1/3 so there are likely to be rounding issues. I would suggest that choosing integer values (eg 33, 33, 34) that simplify the rounding that has to be done by the layout engine.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
.container .panel:last-child{
    margin-right:-1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `flex` to fix this, with a fallback to `float` for older browsers

another solution is to set width of one of time items to `33.3334%` (although it might not work everywhere, I have seen cases where `width: 100%` on element was producing a gap)

Comment: I have tried the 33.3334% but no luck. if I set it 33.33 / 33.33 / 33.34, it just  goes under (no longer 100%) ffs.